# Unity Editor freezing every time player shoots a bullet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, scripting

Alright, so here's what's happening: When I hit play and left click to shoot, unity editor freezes and I have to do the old Ctrl + Alt + Del, now, I am almost certain this script is the source of the issue, because when a bullet is shot, this script is immediately added to it, so here's the script(It's called BulletLife.cs, just letting you know)

```
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletLife : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet;

    public double bulletLifeSpan = 3;
    bool bulletLifeEnded;

    public LayerMask targetMask;
    bool hasHitTarget;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var bulletAge = new System.Timers.Timer(bulletLifeSpan * 1000);
        bulletAge.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        bulletAge.AutoReset = false;

        while(hasHitTarget == false && bulletLifeEnded == false) {
            hasHitTarget = Physics.CheckSphere(bullet.transform.position, bullet.transform.localScale.y, targetMask);
        }

        Destroy(bullet);

        Debug.Log("Finish");
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(System.Object Source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        bulletLifeEnded = true;
    }
}
```

Also, here's the Shoot.cs script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform gun;
    public GameObject bullet;

    public LayerMask targetMask;

    public float bulletSpeed = 1000f;

    bool hasHitTarget = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("LeftClick")) {
            GameObject bulletInstance;
            bulletInstance = Instantiate(bullet, gun.position, new Quaternion(gun.rotation.w, gun.rotation.x, gun.forward.y, gun.rotation.z));
            bulletInstance.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            bulletInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
            bulletInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(gun.up * bulletSpeed);
            bulletInstance.AddComponent<BulletLife>();
            bulletInstance.GetComponent<BulletLife>().bullet = bulletInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I am using Unity 2019.4.15f1

Answer (score 2):

Well everytime you instantiate a bullet in `Start` you do

```
while(hasHitTarget == false && bulletLifeEnded == false) 
{
    hasHitTarget = Physics.CheckSphere(bullet.transform.position, bullet.transform.localScale.y, targetMask);
}
```

this loop will never finish since none of the conditions is changed inside the loop. There either is a hit or not .. but then the parameters for the raycast are never changed, the position isn't updated since you are still in the same frame => endless loop => freeze the main thread completely.

---

What you rather wanted to do is move that thing to `Update` which is called once a frame like e.g.

```
//public GameObject bullet; // not needed

public double bulletLifeSpan = 3;
//bool bulletLifeEnded; // not needed

public LayerMask targetMask;
//bool hasHitTarget; // not needed

void Start()
{
    var bulletAge = new System.Timers.Timer(bulletLifeSpan * 1000);
    bulletAge.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    bulletAge.AutoReset = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, transform.localScale.y, targetMask))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);

        Debug.Log("Finish");
    }
}

private void OnTimedEvent(System.Object Source, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
{
    Destroy(gameObject);

    Debug.Log("Finish");
}
```

---

Or make it a single [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
// If Start returns IEnumerator it is automatically started as Coroutine
// So no need to start an extra routine
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    // Keeps track of how long your bullet exists already
    var bulletAge = 0f;

    while(bulletAge < bulletLifeSpan && !Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, transform.localScale.y, targetMask)) 
    {
        // Increase by the time passed since last frame
        bulletAge += Time.deltaTime;
 
        // "Pause" this routine, render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    Destroy(gameObject);

    Debug.Log("Finish");
}
```

---

Btw note that in `Shoot` you can shorten this a lot

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("LeftClick")) 
    {
        // Note that your quaternion made no sense -> simply pass in the gun.rotation
        var bulletInstance = Instantiate(bullet, gun.position, gun.rotation);
        var rb = bulletInstance.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.useGravity = false;
        rb.AddForce(gun.up * bulletSpeed);
        var life = bulletInstance.AddComponent<BulletLife>();

        // Assigning the gameObject reference is completely unnecessary 
        // within BulletLife simply use "gameObject" as show before
    }
}
```

You could shorten this even more by making sure these components already exist on your prefab object and are configured correctly. Then you wouldn't need any of these line but just Instantiate it.

---

And finally you shouldn't use this`CheckSphere` at all but rather let Unity handle its Collision detection itself and use [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) and configure your [Collision Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) according to your needs!

The issue with your solution is: If your bullet moves fast it might simply pass a target without your `CheckSphere` noting it  namely if its velocity is higher then `localScale.y * 2`.

Comment: I'm new to Quaternions and 3D modeling so I had to try something...

Comment: Also, for some reason, this code fails to destroy the game object (bullet), i tried adding bulletAge.Start() but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Your `Start` method is blocking, thus freezing your game.
You'll have to use `Update` or a `Coroutine` to make your hit tests.

```
    public class BulletLife : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet;

    public double bulletLifeSpan = 3;
    bool bulletLifeEnded;

    public LayerMask targetMask;
    bool hasHitTarget;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
         StartCoroutine(CheckHit(0, bulletLifeSpan));
    }

    private IEnumerator CheckHit(float interval, float lifetime){
        bool checkEveryFrame = interval <= 0;
        WaitForSeconds wait = checkEveryFrame ? null : new WaitForSeconds(interval);
        while(lifetime > 0){
            yield return wait;
            lifetime = lifetime - (checkEveryFrame ? Time.deltaTime : interval);
            hasHitTarget = Physics.CheckSphere(bullet.transform.position, bullet.transform.localScale.y, targetMask);
        
        }
        bulletLifeEnded = true;
        
        Destroy(bullet);

        Debug.Log("Finish");
    }
}
```